# EPERM: operation not permitted error : Prisma . After entering the commands 'npx migrate dev --name init'

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, orm, prisma

I am trying to run Prisma to integrate with MySQL database using node js servers. After migrating the Prisma schema to the MySql database I get the following error on Mac air m1
I have already verified that the DATABASE URL IS CONFIGURED PROPERLY.
I have tried clearing the cache forcefully, reinstalling npm, rebooting the pc, and restarting VsCode.

**EPERM: operation not permitted, utime '/Users/apple/.cache/prisma/master/bcc2ff906db47790ee902e7bbc76d7ffb1893009/darwin-arm64/prisma-fmt'
apple@Apples-MacBook-Air servers %**

When I try to run the server.js file I get the following error

**@prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues
at new PrismaClient (/Users/apple/Desktop/react-i/servers/node_modules/.prisma/client/index.js:3:11)
at Object. (/Users/apple/Desktop/react-i/servers/authenticate.js:7:16)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (/Users/apple/Desktop/react-i/servers/server.js:7:18)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)**

running  **npx prisma generate** gives the first error again

Any help is appreciated

Here is the relevant server code snippet

```
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const addUserToDb = async user => {
    try {
        const newUser = await prisma.users.create({
            data: {
                email: user.email,
                username: user.username,
                password: hashPassword(user.password),
                isAdmin: true,
            },
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(newUser));
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return 'problem adding user to db';
    }
    return 'user added to db';
};

const hashPassword = password => {
    let salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    hashedpwd = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 1000, 64, 'sha512');
    console.log(hashedpwd);
    return hashedpwd;
};
const generateToken = (user, time = '300s') =>
    jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: time });

route.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    let newUser = req.body.userRegister;

    const accessToken = jwt.sign(newUser, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
    res.json({ user: addUserToDb(newUser), token: accessToken });
});

module.exports = route;

//prisma.schema code

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Users {
  id                 String     @id @default(uuid())
  username           String     @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  email              String?    @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  password           String     @db.VarChar(255)
  refreshToken       String?
  passwordResetToken String?
  profileImgUrl      String?
  customers          Customers?
  role               String     @default("user")

  @@map(name: "users")
}

model Services {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  orders      Orders[]
  title       String
  description String
  SAC         String?  @unique @db.VarChar(255)

  @@map(name: "services")
}

model Customers {
  customers   Users    @relation(fields: [customerId], references: [id])
  customerId  String   @unique
  firstName   String
  lastName    String
  phoneNumber Int
  address     String
  State       String
  Pincode     Int
  City        String?
  orders      Orders[]

  @@map(name: "customers")
}

model Orders {
  id         Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  value      Float
  createdAt  DateTime  @default(now())
  service    Services  @relation(fields: [serviceId], references: [id])
  serviceId  Int
  customer   Customers @relation(fields: [customerId], references: [customerId])
  customerId String

  @@map(name: "orders")
}

model Reviews {
  id         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title      String  @db.VarChar(255)
  starRating Int
  content    String?

  @@map(name: "reviews")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Delete the cached Prisma folder at this directory `/Users/<your_apple_username>/.cache/` and reinitialize Prisma to get it working again

Comment: thank you! saved my life.
ps: I need to use ```sudo rm -rf prisma``` in order to delete prisma folder inside .cache on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

In my case. stopping the Node process which was running in the background solved the issue

Comment: Thank you. I was running my backend in another terminal, leading to this error. Closing the backend terminal solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me with the problem was to remove `/Users/apple/.cache/prisma` directory as @Ilamuhil  mentioned, but instead of installing prisma globally again from npm or yarn, i've just run `prisma migrate dev` having it installed only locally in my project, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If sometimes it does not work remove `node_modules`:

```bash
sudo rm -rf node_modules
```

And then:

```bash
npm install

or 

yarn install
```